# Bus error with read-only file system on 9 out of 13 machines

Tags: hard-drive

Machines are just hanging. I can't reboot with sudo reboot, because it gives me bus error.

I see the message about read only file system and this kind of messages in dmesg

[image]

I can guess that the problem is disk related, but as I see there have been bugreports in ubuntu with this kind of problems, so maybe it's not the hardware?

I can't reboot machine manually, because it is in remote location.

So maybe someone can tell what should I do to know for shure if that's a hardware problem or software problem and is there something I can do about it.

Comment: If you can get to a root shell, then this command will for sure reboot it `echo b >/proc/sysrq-trigger`. But be warned it does not do a clean shutdown, it is about as abrupt as pushing the reset button on the machine. If the machine can find the disk after being rebooted, it will probably come up again after a file system check.

Comment: @kasperd I know a administrator password. How to get to a root shell?

Comment: @kasperd sudo -s gives me bus error also after I'm entering correct password

Comment: If this happened simultaneously on 9 machines, then there has got to be some external circumstance responsible for it. Candidates I can imagine would be either a power surge, something shaking the entire rack, extreme temperatures, or humidity.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it probably wasn't simultaneous. It happens periodically on 9 machines I think.

Comment: I have seen the same symptoms on one laptop, but that was at least in part due to the root file system being on a USB flash device. Surely that isn't the case for your servers. Be careful with what you type into that shell though. Entering a shell internal which you haven't used recently could kill your shell. External commands and anything running in a subshell should be safe (that is give you back your prompt even if the command fails). Chances are you can only run commands which are currently in cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24724/discussion-between-user1685095-and-kasperd).

Comment: Since I don't know what is in your cache and what is not. It is difficult for me to tell you which command to use in order to get a root shell. But if `sudo` gives you a password prompt, then the `sudo` executable must be at least partially in cache. The question then is what does `sudo` attempt to execute next. Does it make any difference which command you ask `sudo` to run?

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly surely a problem on your hard disk. You have a bad block.

In such cases, hard disks are simply thrown out in most professional environment, although you can fix it with an `e2fsck -l <file with the list of the bad blocks>`.

In case of a such nearly system freeze situation with a remote server, you can use [sysrqd](https://julien.danjou.info/projects/sysrqd/) to emulate alt/printscreen/ shortcuts from network.